# How is this bit fields based structure calculating 1. the structure's size 2. the difference between pointer values?

Tags: c, struct, alignment, sizeof, bit-fields

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test {
    unsigned int x; // consider int as 4 bytes
    long int y : 33; // consider long as 8 bytes
    unsigned int z;
};
int main()
{
    struct test t;
    unsigned int* ptr1 = &t.x;
    // long int* ptr3 = &t.y;
    unsigned int* ptr2 = &t.z;
    printf("sizeof(struct test)  %lu\n", sizeof(struct test));
    printf("&t.x  %u\n", ptr1);
    printf("&t.z  %u\n", ptr2);
    printf("ptr2 - ptr1  %ld\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

I was expecting

- 4 bytes to be assigned for x
- since the long int is bitfielded, 33 bits -> 4 + 4 bytes are assigned to it but only 33 is used
- 4 bytes are then assigned to z and doesn't take up the remaining space in the previous 8 bytes because there is no 4 complete bytes left.

A total of 16 bytes
and somehow it is 24

How does that work?

Also since order is important in bitfields, if x starts at 3187370912, since it is not a bitfield it gets 4 bytes. The long int gets 8 bytes, even though 33 bits are only used, since the next field is not a bitfield, so it takes additional 4 bytes. So the ptr between x and z should have 4+8 = 12 bytes difference. But the output is 4 bytes.

How does that work?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic works in units of the type, not bytes (unless the type is byte size). If your type is size 32 bits, then the `4` indicates `16` bytes.

Comment: If you change your struct to `struct test {unsigned int x; unsigned int z; long int y : 33;};` it will be of size 16 because of byte padding

Comment: Pragati Bhattad,  Better to use _specified_ matching print specifiers: `printf("sizeof(struct test)  %zu\n", sizeof(struct test));  printf("&t.x  %p\n", (void*) ptr1);  printf("&t.z  %p\n", (void*) ptr2);   printf("ptr2 - ptr1  %td\n", ptr2 - ptr1);`.

Comment: *"The output is 4 bytes"*: no, it is 4 **units**.

Answer (score 0):

In these calls of printf

```
printf("sizeof(struct test)  %lu\n", sizeof(struct test));
printf("&t.x  %u\n", ptr1);
printf("&t.z  %u\n", ptr2);
printf("ptr2 - ptr1  %ld\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
```

there are used wrong conversion specifiers. You need to write

```
printf("sizeof(struct test)  %zu\n", sizeof(struct test));
printf("&t.x  %p\n", ( void * )ptr1);
printf("&t.z  %p\n", ( void * )ptr2);
printf("ptr2 - ptr1  %td\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
```

As for your question then the structure is aligned by the compiler by the value of `sizeof( long int )` to guarantee that the data member `y` will be aligned according to its type. So the compiler placed `4` padding bytes after the variable `x`. As a result  between the pointers `ptr2` and `ptr1` (between the addresses of the data members `z` and `x`) of type `int *` there are `16` bytes. So using the pointer arithmetic the last call of printf outputted the value `4` because `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`..

This bit field

```
long int y : 33;
```

is placed in one object of the type `long int`.